# 500 - Internal server error

Tags: .net, iis, hosting

My site was running well (hosted with plesk). I logged in with Plesk login details and just downloaded web.config file. Meanwhile, my client reported the site is down and shows "500 - Internal server error".
We didn't do any code change or deployment on the server, but just found (.Security) file updated which is available outside the website folder.

The server was restarted, but the issue didn't resolve.

Any suggestion as what may have happened as it was working for years without any issues.

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: I checked the log, but did not find anything which indicates the reason for this issue. Here is the last partial part of the log file. Please let me know if there is something which can help?

Comment: http://www.MYWEBSOULtechnology.com.au/Home.aspx www.MYWEBSOULtechnology.com.au 500 19 5 1380 633 15
2013-08-05 06:47:00 W3SVC18 MYWEBSOUL 175.49.93.445 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - 124.164.12.157 HTTP/1.1 Opera/9.80+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+Presto/2.12.388+Version/12.15 - http://www.MYWEBSOULtechnology.com.au/website-designer/web-overview.aspx www.MYWEBSOULtechnology.com.au 500 19 5 1380 464 15